# Setting Foreign Key in a Rails New Model Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with two foreign keys. I want to create a new record in that model and populate the foreign keys. I have working code. My question is if there is a more appropriate way to do this in Rail. This is the SQL for the model:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`description` varchar(1024) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT '',
`date_entered` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`goal_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ...
```

The following code works:
The pertinent parts of events_controller.rb

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.goal_id = params[:goal_id]
    @event.user_id = current_user.id # Assign to whomever is logged in
    if @event.save
      # return to caller. There is no event show page
      redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def new
    session[:return_to] ||= request.referer
    @event = Event.new
    @event.goal = Goal.find(params[:owner])
  end

private

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit( :description, :goal_id)
  end
end
```

In _new_update_form.html.erb in views/events I have

```
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'goal_id', @event.goal_id %>
```

I have the hidden field to get the goal_id back to the controller when the form is submitted.

In new.html.erb for views/events

```
<%= form_for :event, url: events_path  do |f| %>
  <%= render 'new_update_form', {:f => f, :submit_text => 'Add' } %>
<% end %>
```

I saw post here that suggested using the equivalent of  @event in place of :event in the form_for above. It didn't work when I tried it, but I may have been doing something else wrong.

There problem I was trying to fix was an SQL Insert failure complaining of a missing goal_id. As I mentioned at the start, this code works. Is this the best practice for doing it?

Comment: If the associations allows it you could use something like `@event = current_user.events.new(event_params)` in the controller maybe. That would save a line.

Comment: Are you using the @event.goal_id in a hidden field just to save it again in the controller? Or some code is missing which changes that hidden fields value?

Comment: Yes @preciz. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: I have no say about the SQL, other than that the controller looks fine for me.

Comment: I'm not unhappy with the code as is. There are so many Rails shortcuts. I wanted to use one here if it existed.